# Trapping Excel VBA Slicer click events

Tags: excel, vba, events, slicers

A similar unanswered question lies here: [Excel Macro slicer onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68319266/excel-macro-slicer-onclick-event)

I have a ListObject and a Slicer on that ListObject. The slicer is called "Year". I'm able to trap the on click event with

```
Private Sub Year_Click()
   doCalcsOnFilteredListObject
End Sub
```

Just right click on the slicer heading > Add Macro

Problem is that I want the trapped event to happen, ***after*** the filter selection has been applied. Right now, I trap the event, the filter is never applied, but the calc function runs fine on the (unaltered) listobject.

Comment: Can you add how you have set up the click event?  (I don't want to guess how you've done that in order to test some ideas)

Comment: Just right click on the slicer heading > Add Macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events for ListObjects and Slicers. The Year_Click you have is an event of container object not of SlicerItem.

The workaround is creating a DUMMY worksheet that has SUBTOTAL Formula on A1 Cell and trap a SheetCalculate event on it. So that when you click on Slicer, it recalculates the formula on DUMMY!A1 after filtering.

Procedures:

1. Create a new sheet named "DUMMY" & put a formula in A1 cell: "=SUBTOTAL(109, Table1[YEAR])". (Adjust appropriately to your ListObject & Column names.)
2. Put this VBA procedure.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  If Sh.Name = "DUMMY" Then
    doCalcsOnFilteredListObject
  End If
End Sub
```

3. Select criteria in Slicer.

This should trigger the desired event and call your custom procedure.

Be aware that Automatic Calculation must be turned on. If you want Manual Calculation, there is a technique using Workbook_Open that sets all sheets into Manual Calculation except the DUMMY sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Wils Mils' answer, I personally prefer to place the formula on the sheet itself where the `WorkBook.SlicerCache` is, and use the `Calculate` event of that sheet. In this way you can more clearly separate the code corresponding to each one with the sheet where the associated table is.

If the sheet where the table associated with the `WorkBook.SlicerCache` is located already has formulas that are calculated, you don't need to add any additional formula, just take advantage of the Calculate event to loop through the `.SlicerItems` of the `WorkBook.SlicerCache` and see how many and which ones are selected .

Note that each `WorkBook.SlicerCache` can have multiple instances of `.Slicers` on multiple sheets, but the `.SlicerItems` selected or not are specific to the common `.SlicerCache`.

All the best.